# Symmetry of the (Riemann) curvature tensor of the Riemannian connection: $\nabla_{\nabla_Y Z}W = \nabla_Y(\nabla_Z W)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature, connections

My book is Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes by Loring W. Tu (I'll call this Volume 3), a sequel to both Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Loring W. Tu and Raoul Bott (Volume 2) and An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu (Volume 1).

I refer to [Theorem 22.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EiPz.png) in [Section 22.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EiPz.png). While the term "Riemann curvature tensor" is not introduced until Section 22.6, I believe what [Theorem 22.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EiPz.png) refers to is the Riemann curvature tensor.

For proving [Theorem 22.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EiPz.png), I'm trying to understand what it means when Tu says that adding (22.5) and (22.6) cancels out the $\langle R(Y,Z)X,W \rangle$ term.

I think the canceling out is in that $\langle R(Y,Z)X,W \rangle + \langle R(Y,Z)W,X \rangle = 0$, which I can show assuming $\nabla_{\nabla_Y Z}W = \nabla_Y(\nabla_Z W)$ for all $Y,Z,W \in \mathfrak X(M)$ is true.

**Question** if $\nabla_{\nabla_Y Z}W = \nabla_Y(\nabla_Z W)$ is true: Why is $\nabla_{\nabla_Y Z}W = \nabla_Y(\nabla_Z W)$ true?

**Question** if $\nabla_{\nabla_Y Z}W = \nabla_Y(\nabla_Z W)$ is false: How else do I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\nabla_{\nabla_Y Z}W = \nabla_Y(\nabla_Z W)$ is not true in general.

All Tu means is that $\langle R(Y,Z)X,W \rangle$ in (22.5) will cancel with $\langle R(Y,Z)W,X \rangle$ in (22.6), due to the skew-symmetry (Prop 12.5).

Comment: Oh, I missed this "As an algebraic consequence of these three properties" Thanks!